# Resource for writing assembly[shellcode]

Tags: linux, assembly, shellcode, manpage

I am writing assembly[shellcode] for i386 linux. I wanted to know if there are any man pages or cheats sheets to see which registers need to be set-up for the calls[ read, write, execve] to be made.

Comment: Google "Linux system calls 32 bit".

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can consult `syscall` man-page for syscall ABI on different architectures. For a specific syscall, see the man-page of the corresponding C-library wrapper function which usually includes a `C library/kernel differences` chapter if necessary. For the list of all syscalls see `syscalls` man-page.

For the actual syscall numbers see `asm/unistd.h` header.